# Spring Integration 2 with Quartz scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration.

I've configured a Spring file inbound-channel-adapter, e.g.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="channel1" directory="${location}" prevent-duplicates="true" filename-pattern="*.csv">
        <si:poller>
            <si:interval-trigger interval="1000"/>
        </si:poller>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<si:service-activator input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2" ref="filenameGenerator" method="generate"/>
```

Now this is working fine.
But this needs to be deployed in a clustered environment. I want to make sure that multiple instances in the cluster do not attempt to read the same file. So will this work in such environment?

If no, can I use Quartz scheduler like this:

```
    <file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="channel1" directory="${location}" prevent-duplicates="true" filename-pattern="*.csv">
             <si:poller task-executor="taskExecutor" fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <si:service-activator input-channel="channel1" output-channel="channel2" ref="filenameGenerator" method="generate"/>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="threadCount" value="20"/>
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="consumer"/>
    </bean>
```

Will this work and solve my problem??
Or do I have to use Transaction?

I hope the question is clear.

Thanks,
Adi

Comment: To reiterate the problem,

The issue is with the file inbound-channel-adapter in clustered environment.

E.g when a file is placed in a folder, it should be picked up, processed, and finally rename it.

In cluster, while one instance picks up a particular file, and still processing it, the other node's file adapter also picks up, and tries to process. Second adapter fails with a file not found exception, as the first adapter process and renames that in the meanwhile. So what can I do so that this does not happen????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When multiple processes are reading from the same directory it can be
>   desirable to lock files to prevent them from being picked up
>   concurrently. To do this you can use a FileLocker

Check out the documentation around file lockers [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html). It seems that you can do soemthing like this:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter ... >
  <file:nio-locker/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

> When multiple processes are reading from the same directory it can be
>   desirable to lock files to prevent them from being picked up
>   concurrently. To do this you can use a FileLocker

Comment: I get this error now:  java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file... I have got another channel that rename the file...

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that a quartz-scheduled job executes once and only once within a cluster, configure a persistent, clustered quartz job schedule. Here's a sample config, for Quartz 1.6.6:

```
  <bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <!--        Set whether any jobs defined on this SchedulerFactoryBean should
            overwrite existing job definitions.
      --> 
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" /> 
  <property name="dataSource" ref="myTransactionalDataSource" /> 

<!-- nonTransactionalDataSource is only necessary with clustered Quartz with an XA DataSource.  
  --> 
  <property name="nonTransactionalDataSource" ref="myNonTransactionalDataSource" /> 

 <property name="quartzProperties">
  <props>
  <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WITH(UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?</prop> 
  <!-- 
    Run in cluster.  Quartz ensures persisted jobs are executed once within the 
                      cluster
  --> 
  <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop> 

 <!--   Each node in the cluster must have a unique instance id.  
  --> 
  <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop> 
 <!--   Default clusterCheckinInterval is 15000 
  --> 
  <!--  <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop> 
  --> 
 </props>
  </property>
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" /> 
- <!-- 
        In Quartz 1.6.6, Quartz's ThreadPool interface is used when firing job triggers, 
        in org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread. 
        Quartz 1.x still starts some unmanaged threads, notably org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport's
        ClusterManager which is used when clustered=true. Quartz 2.0 should correct this problem.       
  --> 
  <property name="taskExecutor" ref="myTaskExecutor" /> 
  </bean>
```